# Troubleshooting "[Errno 2] No such file or directory"

Tags: ruby, sass, sublimetext2

I'm getting "permission denied" when I try to use sass. I'm using Sublime Text 2, and the current version of Ruby, and the [bones theme](http://themble.com/bones/).

Here is a screenshot of my terminal/code:

[image]

Here is what it says when I save in SublimeText:

```
[Errno 2] No such file or directory
[cmd:  [u'sass', u'--update', u'/Users/jschreiber/sites/wp-content/themes/eddiemachado-bones-405349e/library/scss/_base.scss:/Users/jschreiber/sites/wp-content/themes/eddiemachado-bones-405349e/library/scss/_base.css', u'--stop-on-error', u'--no-cache']]
[dir:  /Users/jschreiber/sites/wp-content/themes/eddiemachado-bones-405349e/library/scss]
[path: /usr/local/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin]
[Finished]
```

This is my `gem env`:

```
administrators-MacBook-Air:~ jschreiber$ gem env
RubyGems Environment:
  - RUBYGEMS VERSION: 2.0.7
  - RUBY VERSION: 2.0.0 (2013-06-27 patchlevel 247) [x86_64-darwin12.3.0]
  - INSTALLATION DIRECTORY: /Users/jschreiber/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247
  - RUBY EXECUTABLE: /Users/jschreiber/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p247/bin/ruby
  - EXECUTABLE DIRECTORY: /Users/jschreiber/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/bin
  - RUBYGEMS PLATFORMS:
    - ruby
    - x86_64-darwin-12
  - GEM PATHS:
    - /Users/jschreiber/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247
    - /Users/jschreiber/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@global
  - GEM CONFIGURATION:
    - :update_sources => true
    - :verbose => true
    - :backtrace => false
    - :bulk_threshold => 1000
  - REMOTE SOURCES:
    - https://rubygems.org/
```

When I followed the sublime text instructions and ran subl - still getting error:

```
administrators-MacBook-Air:~ jschreiber$ ln -s "/Applications/Sublime Text 2.app/Contents/SharedSupport/bin/subl" ~/bin/subl
ln: /Users/jschreiber/bin/subl: No such file or directory
administrators-MacBook-Air:~ jschreiber$ ln -s "/Applications/Sublime Text 2.app/Contents/SharedSupport/bin/subl" /usr/local/bin/subl
administrators-MacBook-Air:~ jschreiber$ subl
administrators-MacBook-Air:~ jschreiber$ ln -s "/Applications/Sublime Text 2.app/Contents/SharedSupport/bin/subl" ~/bin/subl
ln: /Users/jschreiber/bin/subl: No such file or directory
administrators-MacBook-Air:~ jschreiber$ ln -s "/Applications/Sublime Text 2.app/Contents/SharedSupport/bin/subl" /usr/local/bin/subl
ln: /usr/local/bin/subl: File exists
administrators-MacBook-Air:~ jschreiber$ subl
administrators-MacBook-Air:~ jschreiber$ sites/wp-content/themes/eddiemachado-bones-405349e/library/scss
-bash: sites/wp-content/themes/eddiemachado-bones-405349e/library/scss: is a directory
administrators-MacBook-Air:~ jschreiber$ sass --watch style.scss:../css/style.css
>>> Sass is watching for changes. Press Ctrl-C to stop.
    directory ../css
Errno::EACCES: Permission denied - ../css
            Use --trace for backtrace.
```

Comment: If I add the trace command, I get this http://pastebin.com/Dr2gTNPd

Comment: Don't add screen shots of code if you intend for that to be useful when debugging a problem with your app. We need the real code that we can copy/paste into an editor and run. When you say "the current version of Ruby", what do you mean? Many people know know what the current revision is, you might be wrong, and it will change in the future. Also, the real text helps Google index your question, making it useful for others who might be searching for the same answers. Also, don't put links to significant parts of your question. The links WILL break eventually, making your question worthless.

Comment: @theTinMan Here's everything currently in terminal: http://pastebin.com/CKNcCv5X

As for the actual theme, I haven't altered anything and it can be downloaded directly from the source.

Comment: ruby-2.0.0-p247, updated yesterday

Comment: You're on Mac OS. How did you upgrade your Ruby? What does `gem env` say? PASTE that information into your question, do NOT add another link unless that information exceeds the size available to a question's textbox.

Comment: I used RVM, I believe this was the tutorial I used, along with the actual RVM site http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/ruby/how-to-install-ruby-on-a-mac/

Answer (score 0):

Let's take a look at your "current version of Ruby"...

Your error shows your path to be:

```
[path: /usr/local/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin]
```

Breaking that into something more readable results in:

```
[
  path
  /usr/local/bin
  /usr/local/bin
  /usr/local/bin
  /usr/local/bin
  /usr/local/bin
  /usr/local/bin
  /usr/local/bin
  /usr/local/bin
  /usr/local/bin
  /usr/local/bin
  /usr/local/bin
  /usr/local/bin
  /usr/local/bin
  /usr/local/bin
  /usr/local/bin
  /usr/local/bin
  /usr/local/bin
  /usr/bin
  /bin
  /usr/sbin
  /sbin
]
```

What's wrong with this? Besides the fact that you have 18 redundant instances of `/usr/local/bin` in your path, which is going to slow all your command-line apps as the path is searched, the other problem is that none of them will be the current Ruby if you're using Mac OS unless you installed from source.

> I used RVM

Then you either didn't follow [the directions for installation](http://rvm.io/rvm/install) or you used a system-wide installation of RVM, which isn't necessary or even recommended by the RVM authors. Read the full "installation" directions, then follow the steps in the "Try out your new RVM installation" section on that page.

To use Ruby with RVM, you have to modify your `~/.bash_profile` to load RVM at the shell's startup, plus you have to tell RVM which Ruby to use using:

```
rvm use ruby-2.0.0-p247 --default
```

This is covered in the install directions.

It's also very possible that Sublime isn't set up correctly. Try starting Sublime from the command-line using the `subl` command, then try running your code. If that works, it means Sublime isn't aware of the appropriate path to your RVM-hosted Ruby, and you'll need to fix that. "[Sublime Text 2 Integration With RVM and Rspec: Take Number 2](http://rubenlaguna.com/wp/2012/12/07/sublime-text-2-rvm-rspec-take-2/)" seems reasonable.

The reason starting Sublime using the `subl` command would work differently than opening it via the launcher, is the command-line uses the PATH variable, and the launcher doesn't. To reconcile those you'll need to modify a plist file. See "[How to set PATH for Finder-launched applications](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/51677/how-to-set-path-for-finder-launched-applications)" for information.

Comment: Ok, how do I solve this then? Like I said, I am not an experienced user.

Comment: You read the directions carefully, and don't believe everything you read on the internet when it says it's the directions to do something. There is a huge body of out-of-date information out there, and an even bigger body of information that is just plain-wrong. Follow the directions on the source sites, such as RVM's. Even Stack Overflow can be wrong, but with the peer-reviewing process here your odds are better of getting useful information IF you read carefully.

Comment: subl command isn't found when I try that.

administrators-MacBook-Air:~ jschreiber$ subl

-bash: subl: command not found

administrators-MacBook-Air:~ jschreiber$ subl --help

-bash: subl: command not found

Comment: Then you need to follow the Sublime Text [installation directions](http://www.sublimetext.com/docs/2/osx_command_line.html).

Comment: It's possible I did a system-wide installation of RVM, though I never used the sudo command. Would it be simpler to totally uninstall/reinstall than to try and repair?

Comment: @Jackie - Try restarting Terminal.app then running `subl` again to see if it works. Also, there's a pretty clear guide on how to change the `PATH` used by graphical applications under OSX Mountain Lion [over at Unix&Linux.SE](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/89077/19512). It's the only way I've found to permanently (between restarts) change the `PATH` for **all** GUI apps not launched from the command line.